# UK PR for Indian IT Professionals

Tags: united-kingdom, india, pr

If my employer asks me to travel to UK and I am given an ICT tier 2 long term visa which is 3+2 years after which I have to come back. My question is, if I travel with that visa and wish to stay longer than 5 years so that I can apply for an ILR, what are my options. One way I can think of is if I take my wife as a dependent and if she gets a job before my visa expires and her employer sponsors her for next 5 years, so I can then shift as her dependent and stay for longer time, in that situation can we both apply for ILR? Or are there any other options?

Comment: The same processes to acquire ILR applies to all irregardless of their country of origin. Your question is unclear. Are you asking if this is a different means of acquiring ILR outside of that which is stated in the UK government rules?

Comment: Let me explain a scenario. If my employer asks me to travel to UK and I am given an ICT tier 2 long term visa which is 3+2 years after which I have to come back. My question is, if I travel with that visa and wish to stay longer than 5 years so that I can apply for an ILR, what are my options. One way I can think of is if I take my wife as a dependent and if she gets a job before my visa expires and her employer sponsers her for next 5 years, so I can then shift as her dependent and stay for longer time, in that situation can we both apply for ILR? Or are there any other options?

Comment: That actually clears things up nicely. I would suggest you edit this scenario into your question. BTW, the route you suggest is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. So in that case, I am assuming I can only apply for ILR after 10 years? or can it be applied earlier?